# Extract IP and DHCP and set to variable from ipconfig /all. Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ipconfig

I am trying to extract the DHCP status and IP address from ipconfig /all and set it to a variable.

Can this be done?

Comment: Will the name of the adapter be known ahead of time?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier using `Netsh` try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "skip=2 tokens=* delims=" %%a in (
  'netsh interface ipv4 show config name^="local area connection"'
) do (
    set /a cnt+=1 
    if !cnt! equ 3 (
      goto :break
    ) ELSE (echo(%%a
  )
)  
:break
```

Change local area connecton to suit your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I'm doing this with `grep`.

I don't know exactly what you need, but for example if you need the DHCP-server:

```
for /F %%i in ('ipconfig -all ^| grep "DHCP Server" ^| grep -Eo '[0-9][0-9.]+'') do set DHCPServer=%%i
```

and for the local IP:

```
for /F %%j in ('ipconfig ^| grep "IPv4" ^| grep -Eo '[0-9][0-9.]+'') do set IpAdress=%%j
```

Both commands are working inside a batch file.